# There is already an object named 'tblPerson_Gender_FK' in the database

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, constraints

In SQL Server 2014, I wanted to create a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE tblPerson
    ADD CONSTRAINT tblPerson_Gender_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY(Gender) REFERENCES tblGender(ID);
```

But I always get this error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 30
>   There is already an object named 'tblPerson_Gender_FK' in the database.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 30
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is my table

```
create table tblPerson
(
    ID int Primary Key NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(max) Not null ,
    Email varchar(max) Not null,
    Gender int
)
```

and another

```
create table tblGender
(
     ID int not null Primary key,
     Gender varchar(max) 
)
```

Comment: The error telling you that there is already an object named as 'tblPerson_Gender_FK'  check your table relation's in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that you have a another foreign key that named `tblPerson_Gender_FK`.

You can change the foreign key name;

```
ALTER TABLE tblPerson
ADD CONSTRAINT tblPerson_Gender_2_FK FOREIGN KEY(Gender) REFERENCES tblGender(ID);
```

or you can drop existing foreign key. But I don't recommend it because dropping a existing foreign key might cause unexpected data problems on related tables.